# Is it possible to set the database connection string in Unit Test Project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

Current I need my unit test project to connect to database but based on the environment its part of. So If I run the test via mstest.exe on Server A, then I want the database connection string to point to "DatabaseA", and if I run it on Server B, I want the point to "DatabaseB". Note: "DatabaseA" can be dev evn and "Database C" can be production environment.

I have ConfigurationSettings calls in the MS Test project:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WF.ZTDD
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class ConfigurationSettings
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// set application default data directory
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">TestContext</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

BUT NOT SURE What exactly do to get the argument that I can pass via mstest.exe

i.e.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /testcontainer: SomeTestProject.dll /runconfig:../TestSettings1.testsettings /env:prodution


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /testcontainer: SomeTestProject.dll /runconfig:../TestSettings1.testsettings /env:development
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need to connect to the database? That sounds more like an integration test to me. You should be mocking the classes that provide database access.

Comment: Yeah its not true unit test and its a mixture of unit testing and integration testing. These tests are set up to connect to db and do simple checks before pusing builds out. mstest.exe will be execute via command line.

Comment: You can specify different connection strings by dbName in the config file and then pass the name of the context you want into the DB constructor.

Comment: @AlexKrups correct. I am just not sure how to connect mstest.exe command line execution with custom settting like env:development to MS test project. In the AssemblyInit method is it possible to check for "env" args?

Comment: Why not just have the test code itself check its environment and specify the db name based on that

Comment: @AlexKrups to be more specific we have multiple dev env and its own db. So beploying to DEV2 for example we would just want to pass it argument in the mstest.exe call and simple figure out which database to point to. Command Line call is not ran in the DEV2 env, but we deploy to it from local computer.